# N-dimensional array generic methods

Tags: java

I asked a similar question yesterday and got a brilliant [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158922/three-methods-to-serialize-7-6-and-3-dimensional-int-arrays), but unsure how I could adapt these methods.

The methods perform a BFS on a state and then store the values in a multi-dimensional array.

You can see that the code is repeating itself, just with different array dimensions.

**Method 1:**

```
    public void bfs2(int[][][] three, PDB15Tile.State s, int[] storedNums, String fileName) throws IOException {
        Queue<PDB15Tile.State> q = new LinkedList<>();
        int[] positions = new int[storedNums.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < storedNums.length; i++) {
            positions[i] = getPatternPosition(storedNums[i], s.getState());
        }
        three[positions[0]][positions[1]][positions[2]] = 0;
        q.add(s);
        PDB15Tile.State current;
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            current = q.poll();
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(current.getState()));
            for (PDB15Tile.State neighbour : current.findNeighbours2()) {
                // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(neighbour.getState()));
                for (int i = 0; i < storedNums.length; i++) {
                    positions[i] = getPatternPosition(storedNums[i], neighbour.getState());
                }
                if (three[positions[0]][positions[1]][positions[2]] == 0) {
                    three[positions[0]][positions[1]][positions[2]] = neighbour.getH();
                    q.add(neighbour);
                }

            }

        }
        serializeArrayToFile(three, fileName);
    }
```

**Method 2:**

```
    public void bfs2(int[][][][][][] six, PDB15Tile.State s, int[] storedNums, String fileName) throws IOException {
        Queue<PDB15Tile.State> q = new LinkedList<>();
        int[] positions = new int[storedNums.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < storedNums.length; i++) {
            positions[i] = getPatternPosition(storedNums[i], s.getState());
        }
        six[positions[0]][positions[1]][positions[2]][positions[3]][positions[4]][positions[5]] = 0;
        q.add(s);
        PDB15Tile.State current;
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            current = q.poll();
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(current.getState()));
            for (PDB15Tile.State neighbour : current.findNeighbours2()) {
                // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(neighbour.getState()));
                for (int i = 0; i < storedNums.length; i++) {
                    positions[i] = getPatternPosition(storedNums[i], neighbour.getState());
                }
                //System.out.println(six[positions[0]][positions[1]][positions[2]][positions[3]][positions[4]][positions[5]]);
                if (six[positions[0]][positions[1]][positions[2]][positions[3]][positions[4]][positions[5]] == 0) {
                    six[positions[0]][positions[1]][positions[2]][positions[3]][positions[4]][positions[5]] = neighbour.getH();
                    q.add(neighbour);
                }

            }

        }
        serializeArrayToFile(six, fileName);
    }
```

How do I determine the number of dimensions of the object that is passed in and then manipulate the array accordingly?

Comment: May I ask why are you using multi-dimensional arrays for this, that is, what is the purpose of `three` and `six` arrays? I don't see any iterating over the 3 or 6 dimensions. You are only ever retrieving values from fixed indexes, which makes me wonder if your choice of data structures is correct.

Comment: @RK1 You might be interested in reading this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158922/three-methods-to-serialize-7-6-and-3-dimensional-int-arrays#comment300947_158922

Comment: Thats the whole idea of the 3 and 6 dimension arrays @RK1 to prevent having to iterate over the array. The indexs represent value positions, its called sparse indexing